# AsyncTask and CameraDemo problem

Tags: android

From my main page I set an alarm, this is caught in a receiver class which then starts a new activity.   This new activity starts an aSyncTask which starts a new CameraDemo class (from the code found on here).    When a photo is taken the process moves eventually to the jpegCallBack.   At this point I want it to return to  the activity that contains the aSyncTask that called it but when the process reaches the end of the jpagCallBack it seems to pause somewhere but I know not where -not onPostExecute or onPause.   Perhaps it has something to do with my not understanding what can be done with aSyncTask.   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with a photo is taken? Automatically or by the user?

Comment: sorry for not being clear - I code the takePicture method so azutomatically I guess

Answer (score 0):

A very good article on AsycTask can be found [here](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-thread-constructs-part-3.html). This will give you a better understanding.

Comment: my browser says it cant be found

Comment: oops ! Fixed the link. Sry for that.